# Change tabBarItem image programmatically

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

Using iOS14.0.1, Swift5.3, Xcode12.0.1,

I would like to dynamically change the image of a UITabBarController's tabBarItem

Here is my code:

```
self.tabBarCtrl?.viewControllers?[2].tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Sign_ready")
self.tabBarCtrl?.viewControllers?[2].tabBarItem.selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Sign_ready")
```

However, in my App, there are two problems

a) The image does change but is way too large
b) The color of the image is wrong

How can I get rid of the two problems ?

Here a screenshot of how it currently looks with the code above:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **About The Size**
   You can change the size Image preview check the size (pixels) of the other two images and use the same size
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIbaV.png)
   you can set your images sizewise as in this image

2. Image Color

a. First set your image to be always template

firstviewcontrolle.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "database copy")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)

b. Secondly use this code to set the tint color

UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.black